# Can anyone help solve a linear algebra problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Let $u,v$ be vectors such that $||u|| = 2, ||v|| = \sqrt3$ , and $u \cdot v = 1$. Find ||u + v||.

So far I calculated $\dfrac{u\cdot v}{||u||*||v||}=\cos(\theta)$
and then with one angle and two sides in the triangle known, I can calculate the length of $(u-v)$ as the third side of the triangle.

Answer (score 4):

$$
|| u + v ||^2 = (u + v) \cdot (u + v) = \ldots
$$

Comment: I see, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assumed it was a 2 component vector for each vector.
$u=<a,b>$ and $v=<c,d>$

$||u||=2$ means $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=2$

$||v||=\sqrt{3}$ means $\sqrt{c^2+d^2}=\sqrt{3}$

$u \cdot v=1$ means $a c+b  d=1$

**Finding $||u+v||$ now**

$||u+v||=\sqrt{(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2}$

Expand inside the square root a bit

$||u+v||=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+2(ac+bd)}$

Comment: I see, thank you